# Create API Key and verify cross-domain in nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, jwt

I'm new to nodejs, and I'm trying to create and REST_API server, the thing is:

1- I have user registration and login currently working using passport

What i am a bit confuse is:

When a user get access to they're dashboard, i want to have and button that says (Generate your API Key). Then the user will use this key in header requests to my REST_API. That's where i'm not understanding, what should i use to get the above flow?

I tried using JWT to generate a token, but that was only creating the token when user login, and i don't want the user to have to login everytime.

Here's my login route:

```
app.post('/api/login', passport.authenticate('local-login'), function (req, res) {
    res.json({ message: req.authInfo, user_id: req.user.id, user_email: req.user.local.email, loggedin: true });
});
```

If there's something else i have to provide, please ask ok?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*When a user get access to they're dashboard...*

Make a post request to an endpoint, pass the userid, that way you will know which user the key it’s been generated . Generate the key and return it. You can store it in cache or session to use during the session

*i don't want the user to have to login overtime...*

If you don’t want to make your user login everytime. You could store user and pass in browser cache(encrypt the pass). so, when user heads to the app you have to check if user and pass are in cache. if so, log the user in.